# wordList - Hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So I was creating this hangman game with a book (Invent your own computer games in python). It shows me this **words** with these set of animals. 
But what I don't understand is how come the **wordList** is related to **words**:

```
words = 'ant babboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole rat raven rhino shark sheep spider toad turkey turtle wolf wombat zebra'

def getRandomWord(wordList):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1 )
    return wordList[wordIndex]
```

Comment: they are not. You can create a wordList for your words if you split them at spaces:  `wordList = words.split()` - this will create a list - if you have a `"sabertooth lion"` in you list it make a list of `["sabertooth" , "lion"] from it though - but thats a story for another day.-

Comment: If you need a random element from the list it is better to use `one = random.choice(wordList)`  - no indexing into it is involved that way - you simply get one element from the list. See the docu for random at [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: `newword = getRandomWord(words.split())` will create a new random word. You might want to read about pyhton style guide at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - your naming conventions are off. you also want to save the splitted wordlist and not `spli()` for each random animal you need

Answer (score 0):

Because wordList is a parameter of the getRandomWord function, which takes a list as an argument.

Upon calling the function with:

```
getRandomWord(words)
```

it will now set the value of wordList to the words list when running the function code.

Comment: Oh, your right, I learned Ruby as my first language and in Ruby the are called arrays, haha

Answer (score 0):

The wordlist is given as a parameter to the function, and it isn't something fixed, think of it as a placeholder for a string to be passed in. 
You can call that function with either a variable named words or any other variable as long as it is a string. To help you understand how the placeholder works let's say you have a different variable containing a string:

```
notwords = 'ant babboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole rat raven rhino shark sheep spider toad turkey turtle wolf wombat zebra'
```

Now you can call the function with this parameter like this:

```
getRandomWord(notwords)
```

Try this and it'll work too. This won't probably show anything and to see the return you will need to do:

```
print(getRandomWord(notwords))
```